# javascript passing functions as arguments

Tags: javascript, function, arguments

i am a newbie in the world of programming, so i would apreciate to give me( if so) simple answers in my javascript problem.

```
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937, 2005, 1998];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {
var arrRes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
}
return arrRes;
}

function calculateAge(el) {
return 2018 - el;
}
var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);
console.log(ages);
```

can someone explain step by step what happens behind thse scenes??? because i cannot understand why el assigns to i...

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking how parameters work?

Comment: "why el assigns to i" — It doesn't. The only assignments to `i` are `var i = 0` and `i++`.

Comment: Yes , my mistake, it assigns to arr[i].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The i in the for loop is used to reference an index in the array: `arr[0] = 1990, arr[1] = 1965, arr[2] = 1937 etc.`

In this case the for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i]));
}
```

calls the passed function fn (which is calculateAge(): `var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);`) on each element in the array. The function uses el to refer to the element after it has been passed in as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is very basic just try using console.log to see the actual values passed around i have put some comments to help.

```js
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937, 2005, 1998];

function arrayCalc(arr, fn) {//fn is function which will execute with current array element as argument
var arrRes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arrRes.push(fn(arr[i])); //fn:calculateAge(arr[i])
}
return arrRes;
}

function calculateAge(el) {//el is argument 
return 2018 - el;//substract the argument from 2018
}
var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);//passing calculateAge function as argument as function pointer
console.log(ages);
```

Comment: Thank you Kumar for your quick response. You rock!!!!... Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Things are pretty basic like setting an array

```
//setting a array
var years = [1990, 1965, 1937, 2005, 1998]; 

//creating a function
function calculateAge(el) {
   return 2018 - el; // this will subtract every el with 2018
}

//calling a function, pass year variable & calculateAge function as argument of arrayCalc function and store its result on ages variable
var ages = arrayCalc(years, calculateAge);
console.log(ages); // show the result on console
```

If I break down you `arrayCalc(arr, fn)`, this is what happening under the hood.
The `for` loop processing each element of `years` array and calls the `calculateAge()` method, get the result from it after subtracting it by **2018** and pushes the result to `arrRes` array everytime, finally returns `arrRes` and assign it to `ages` variable.

```
var arrRes = []
var result1 = 2018-1990;
arrRes = [result1];

var result2 = 2018-1965;
arrRes = [result1,result2];

var result3 = 2018-1937;
arrRes = [result1,result2,result3];

var result4 = 2018-2005;
arrRes = [result1,result2,result3,result4];

var result5 = 2018-1998;
arrRes = [result1,result2,result3,result4,result5];
```

**Output:** `Array [ 28, 53, 81, 13, 20 ]`

Comment: oh thank you  so much Sunny, you guys rocking here. stackoverflow is a new world for me!!!!!!

Comment: @GeorgePolitis I did an edit again, Hope it will help you to clearly understand what is happening inside. Happy Coding. :)